# Insert a record having timestamp(6) field from Oracle to Postgresql via dblink bug?, lose timestamp precision?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, timestamp, odbc, dblink

I am in trouble while inserting a new record to postgresql from oracle database server. After insert a new record into postgresql, I lose precision of timestamp fields, all digits which refers to microsecond had been lose. Here is my sample code:

```
declare
   v_date timestamp(6):=to_timestamp('2013-06-04 12:03:01.123456','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6');
begin
   dbms_output.put_line (v_date);
   insert into "public"."DAS_ITEM"@PG_LINK 
   ("DOCKID","CANDY_ITM_NBR","MODIFIED_ON") VALUES (1,3, v_date);
commit;
end;
```

After running the pl/sql, I would like to query the data from postgres directly

```
select "DOCKID","CANDY_ITM_NBR", to_char("MODIFIED_ON", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.US') from "DAS_ITEM";
```

and here is the result:

```
  DOCKID     | CANDY_ITM_NBR |     MODIFIED_ON
  -----------+---------------+---------------------------
           1 |             3 | 2013-06-04 12:03:01.000000
```

Currently, the value of **MODIFIED_ON** field is '2013-06-04 12:03:01.000000', I expect the value of **MODIFIED_ON** was **2013-06-04 12:03:01.123456**

Please help me, I am in trouble for 36 hours.

Comment: Maybe simply a display issues with the SQL client you are using to query the Postgres database? What  does selecting `to_char("MODIFIED_ON", 'yyyy-mm-dd hh42:mi:ss.US')` against the Postgres table show you?

Comment: I have edit my post with to_char/2 function. All precision of microsecond was lost.

Comment: What is the data type of column `MODIFIED_ON`?

Comment: the data type of **MODIFIED_ON** in postgres server is: timestamp(6). I can insert/update **MODIFIED_ON** with 6-digit precision in psql without error.

Comment: of course you tried passing text without casting `v_date` to timestamp?..

Comment: @VaoTsun, yes, I have tried it, I have tried to passing pure text "2013-06-04 12:03:01.123456", it doesn't work. Of course it will work if I am at psql, but not in the pl/sql. This is error message if I pass pure text to **MODIFIED_ON** : `ORA-28534: Heterogeneous Services preprocessing error`. here is the gist for the error: [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7c03dd0f9fb2b37e3c712ddecb2f5944)

Comment: and if you dont limit it to timestamp(6)?.. leaving blank for all nine

Comment: @VaoTsun, it would be definitely a bad idea to insert text instead of timestamp values.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit surely - I did not work with Oracle for years, so just suggesting back ingeneering the error - if it cuts precision on insert or on transform

Comment: @VaoTsun, first of all, postgresql's datatype does not support timestamp(9), the maximum precision is 6. On the other hand, I can understand your solution to use pure text instead of timestamp data type value; Postgres DID support inserting timestamp using pure text using psql with certain format. This issue is weird.

Comment: There is a dirty way to solve this issue is to CREATE a new column named **MODIFIED_ON_VARCHAR**::varchar, along with a trigger in postgresql server. This is a after update/insert trigger, It will update the **MODIFIED_ON** after insert/update sql(s) finished, However, I dont like this work around, too messy.

Comment: @NguyenVinhLinh I know the max length of timestamp in postgres. I was assuming the problem could be the `Heterogeneous Services` with limited timestamp conversion

Comment: @VaoTsun, Oh I see your point.  Is there anything that i can work around this solution :v , so scrary with db migration now. :v

Comment: After seeing the error, I would personnaly take the "too messy" option to pass oracle timestamps as they are to a text field and process then in postgres, by just trimming to six digits after last dot and casting to timestamp...

Comment: I am not familiar with ODBC Gateway, but I just found ODBC parameter `BTD`: Bind TIMESTAMP as DATE, see [Using the Oracle ODBC Driver](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_odbc.htm#ADFNS1183)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, I believe that the default value BTD is TIMESTAMP instead of DATE. [link here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_odbc.htm#ADFNS1113). Oracle claims that:    

        Bind TIMESTAMP as DATE (BTD Connect String)

        Added the new connection option, Bind TIMESTAMP as DATE, that 
        allows you to bind the ODBC driver SQL_TIMESTAMP data type to the 
        Oracle DATE data type instead of to the Oracle TIMESTAMP data type 
       (which is the default).

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, In addition, I am also in trouble to fetch timestamp data from PostgreSQL, the precision in microsecond has been lost. I have carefully write PL/SQL and print the data, all 6-digit precision has been lost and replaced by zero(s)